# Integration by parts VS fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation, absolute-continuity

Let $f\in BV[-1,1]$ such that $\forall \phi\in C^\infty_c(-1,1)$ continuous functions with compact support, we have
$$\int_{-1}^1 f'\phi \ d\lambda=-\int_{-1}^1 f\phi' \ d\lambda$$
I have to prove that $f\in AC[-1,1]$. Of course, thanks to the fundamental theorem of calculus it would be enough to prove that
 for almost all $x\in (-1,1)$ $$\int_{-1}^x f(s)ds=f(x)-f(-1)$$
but I cannot achieve this result starting only from $C^\infty_c$ functions

Comment: Let $F(x)=\int^x_{-1}f'(t)dt$. We have  $F(x)\phi(x)=\int^x_{-1}(f'(t)\phi(t)+F(t)\phi'(t))dt.$ Evaluating at $x=1,$ we get  $0=\int^1_{-1}(f'(t)\phi(t)+F(t)\phi'(t))dt\Rightarrow \int^1_{-1}(f(t)\phi'(t)-F(t)\phi'(t))dt=\int^1_{-1}(f(t)-F(t))\phi'(t))dt.$ Then, $f-F$ should be constant but I have not proved it yet.

Comment: I arrived to the same result: $f-F$ is $L^2$ orthogonal to the set of functions which are the derivative of a $C^\infty_c$ function. However since this set isn't dense in $BV[-1,1]$ we cannot say anything

Comment: I think I have a proof of this now. Please see my answer.

Comment: $f'$ exists almost everywhere, and is $L^1$ so you $define$ the function $F$ by the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F(x)=\int^x_{-1}f'(t)dt$ and let $\phi\in C^{\infty}_c((-1,1)]).$

We have  $F(x)\phi(x)=\int^x_{-1}(f'(t)\phi(t)+F(t)\phi'(t))dt.$

Evaluating at $x=1,$ we get  $0=\int^1_{-1}(f'(t)\phi(t)+F(t)\phi'(t))dt\Rightarrow$

$\int^1_{-1}(f(t)\phi'(t)-F(t)\phi'(t))dt=\int^1_{-1}(f(t)-F(t))\phi'(t))dt=0$

Now, suppose $w\in C_c^{\infty}(-1,1)$. Then, if $z(x)=\int^x_{-1}w(t)dt$ satisfies $\int^1_{-1}w(t)dt=0$  then $z\in C_c^{\infty}(-1,1)$ and $z'=w$. So, $\int^1_{-1}(f-F)wdt=0$ for all such functions $w$.

But $\overline{C_c^{\infty}(-1,1)}=L^2([-1,1])$ so we have that if $w\in L^2([-1,1])$ satisfies $\int^1_{-1}w(t)dt=0$, then $\int^1_{-1}(f-F)wdt=0$.

Set $K=\int^1_{-1}(f-F)dt$ and $h(t)=f(t)-F(t)-K$. Then, $\int^1_{-1}h(t)dt=0$ so $\int^1_{-1}h(t)(f(t)-F(t))dt=0$ and unwinding the definitions, this implies that $\int^1_{-1}h^2dt=\int^1_{-1}(f-F)hdt-K\int^1_{-1}hdt=0.$ It follows that $f-F-K=0$ a.e. $\lambda.$

Comment: Ok, the key to your proof is that if $C^\infty_c[-1,1]$ is dense in $L^2[-1,1]$ then the set of functions that are the derivative of a $C^\infty_c[-1,1]$ function is dense into the $L^2[-1,1]$ function which have $0$ as inegral, right?

Comment: @DavideMaran  Yes,  exactly.